# Error:(130, 18) The method observeOn(Scheduler) is undefined for the type Observable<ClientLogin.Response>

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

i am getting error that  is cannot resolve symbol observeOn(rx.Scheduler) in this code, please help me

```
 private void loginProcess(String email, String password) 
 {
        mSubscriptions.add(NetworkUtil.getRetrofit(email, password).login()
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(this::handleResponse,this::handleError));
 }
```

dependencies that i have added are:

```
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
 compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
 compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.0'
 compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
```

Comment: Did you import `io.reactivex.Observable` or `android.database.Observable`?

Comment: There are no imports that you are suggesting, please go through this GitHub link that i am providing and help me, Thankyou [link](https://github.com/iwayankit/android-nodejs/issues/1) @david.mihola